# phpbrew imgttftext function not found

Tags: php, laravel, gd, imagettftext

On Mac OSX Yosemite using PHPBrew.

I am using Laravel with a git package called CodeItNowIn/Barcode which uses the GD library. There is an undefined function error:

> Call to undefined function CodeItNow\BarcodeBundle\Generator\imagettftext()' in /Volumes/Blacktie/Sync/Websites/CLIENTELE/acgamesonline.com/mb/vendor/codeitnowin/barcode/CodeItNow/BarcodeBundle/Generator/CINFontFile.php:203

I am using PHPBrew with a switch between 7.0.1 and 5.5.12 - this is necessary to control my projects.

Seems like something to do with the phpbrew installation - but I can't pinpoint what.

Comment: just the ttf functions fail, but the rest of the gd works? offhand guess: gd was compiled without the freetype library, so the truetype font-related functions are disabled/missing?

Comment: That's where I am at - correct. At one point imagecreate failed. I reinstalled php with gd with freetype and with truetype, and now imagecreate doesn't fail - but imagettftype does.

Let me know if you need me to send something to help out! The offhand guess was my same guess - and I'm not sure why it's not working.